# How to install own app on Ubuntu

Tags: compilation, makefile, installation

I created an app on my Windows machine and now I want to install it on my Linux machine. It has several headers and source files so I thought it is best to upload it on Github. I did that and I also created a Makefile, but I get a lot of errors when I try to install it directly from the folder.

Given the fact that it is for personal use only, is there a way to manually compile each file and then run it as a whole?

Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all debug profile install uninstall clean

all: $(PROG)

$(PROG): $(FILES)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -o $(PROG) $(FILES) $(LIBS)

debug: $(FILES)
    $(CC) $(DEBUGFLAGS) -o $(PROG) $(FILES) $(LIBS)

profile: $(FILES)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -pg -o $(PROG) $(FILES) $(LIBS)

install: $(PROG)
    cp -f $(PROG) /usr/sbin/
    cp -f $(PROG).1 /usr/man/man1/ || cp -f $(PROG).1 /usr/local/man/man1/

uninstall:
    rm -f /usr/sbin/$(PROG)
    rm -f /usr/man/man1/$(PROG).1 || rm -f /usr/local/man/man1/$(PROG).1

clean:
    rm -f $(PROG)
```

Comment: GitHub has nothing to do with installation, it's just a place to store the code. Could you give a [mcve] of the code and makefile, and expand on *"a lot of errors"*?

Comment: The problem with the makefile lies here:                                                                 `cp -f $(PROG) /usr/sbin/                                                                            cp -f $(PROG).1 /usr/man/man1/ || cp -f $(PROG).1 /usr/local/man/man1/` while the error is ”no such file or directory”.           I tried to solve it by myself but I failed.   Also, I did not provide an verifiable example of the code because I asked for an alternative not for a code check. If, however, the code is mandatory, I will add it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  I added part of the makefile. Hope that helps.

Comment: What was the portion of the error message just before "no such file or directory"?

Comment: cp: cannot create regular file „/usr/man/man1”: no such file or directory

Comment: If your system doesn't have a `/usr/man` directory, it probably has a `/usr/share/man` directory, as per the [Linux filesystem hierarchy standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s11.html#usrsharemanManualPages), so modify your makefile appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your basic approach is fine, you are missing a couple of details, and you are breaking a few conventions that were established for a reason.

Details:

- Your definitions for `$(PROG)`, `$(FILES)` and `$(LIBS)` aren't included.
- You try to copy a file to a directory without ensuring its existence.  The `install` utility is often used instead of `cp` to handle stuff like this.

Conventions:

- You don't appear to use `root` privileges only when necessary. Compile as a regular user; only run `make install` as `root`, e.g. using `sudo`; or better, avoid even that.
- You're trying to place files into `/usr/bin/` and `/usr/man`, where the package management system installs files, so you risk confusing it.  Don't. If you need to make third-party software, such as your own, available to all users on the system, just install to `/usr/local/` or `/opt`, which exist for this purpose. Adjust `$PATH` and `$MANPATH` accordingly.  If it's just for your own personal use, you can install to directories under `$HOME`.
- Make the top level target directory to install to a variable in your `Makefile`. It is often called `$(DESTDIR)`.